# How to read the text at image box during creating new google account with WebDriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, captcha

How to read the text in image box while creating new google account using WebDriver in java. I am creating a new gmail account using WebDriver in java. I am NOT able to read the text present in Image box. Can anybody help me on this issue?

The Code I have used for that is:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.id("link-signup")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("Swamy");
driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("Kumar");
driver.findElement(By.id("GmailAddress")).sendKeys("Skumar081112");
driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("Swamy@123");
driver.findElement(By.id("PasswdAgain")).sendKeys("Swamy@123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='month-label']/span/div
                         /div")).sendKeys("November");
driver.findElement(By.id("BirthDay")).sendKeys("16");
driver.findElement(By.id("BirthYear")).sendKeys("1978");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Gender']/div/div")).sendKeys("Male");
driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryPhoneNumber")).sendKeys("9000000000");
driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryEmailAddress")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("HomepageSet")).click();
String imgmsg = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='recaptcha_image']
                 /img")).toString();
System.out.println(imgmsg);
```

Help will be appreciated...

Comment: well, that text is there to prevent any automated gmail creation... This technique could be used for spamming. Please consider if you really need to test something which has been probably tested by Google team itself...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just want to know how this text has be captured using webdriver in Java

Comment: If that would be possible, it would be against the whole idea of CAPTCHA. I.E.: Should be human readable, but not machine readable

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to create the new account in GMail without entering that text.

Comment: Nope. That is not possible. Reason for it is to prevent spammers to create thousands of accounts

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your valuable information to me.. Thanks once again.

Comment: This is not the purpouse Selenium WebDriver was made. Why would you actually need to automate creation of google accounts?

Comment: why should not we try to automate the creation of google account?

Comment: because: 5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services **through any automated means** (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.

Comment: The purpose of CAPTCHA is to prove you are Human, not Machine. That's why, it is not possible to automate

Comment: Thanks Ripon for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can't

That text is called a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) it is designed to stop automated systems from creating accounts (and is obviously doing a pretty good job).

> A CAPTCHA (pron.: /ˈkæp.tʃə/) is a type of challenge-response test
>   used in computing as an attempt to ensure that the response is
>   generated by a human being. The process usually involves a computer
>   asking a user to complete a simple test which the computer is able to
>   grade. These tests are designed to be easy for a computer to generate
>   but difficult for a computer to solve, but again easy for a human. If
>   a correct solution is received, it can be presumed to have been
>   entered by a human. A common type of CAPTCHA requires the user to type
>   letters and/or digits from a distorted image that appears on the
>   screen. Such tests are commonly used to prevent unwanted internet bots
>   from accessing websites, since a normal human can easily read a
>   CAPTCHA, while the bot cannot process the image letters and therefore,
>   cannot answer properly, or at all. Although most CAPTCHAs are letter
>   pictures randomly generated, many of them have become difficult even
>   for a human to read , so picture CAPTCHAs were created in which a
>   human is shown a simple test to show a picture of a certain animal
>   (given few animal pictures), which is simple for a human being to
>   process, and therefore easy to pick, while a bot cannot process and
>   solve the question because although it can analyze the picture, it
>   cannot easily guess the animal. The term "CAPTCHA" was coined in 2000
>   by Luis von Ahn, Manuel Blum, Nicholas J. Hopper, and John Langford
>   (all of Carnegie Mellon University). It is an acronym based on the
>   word "capture" and standing for "Completely Automated Public Turing
>   test to tell Computers and Humans Apart". Carnegie Mellon University
>   attempted to trademark the term on 15 October 2004,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) but the
>   trademark application was abandoned on 21 April 2008.[2] A CAPTCHA is
>   sometimes described as a reverse Turing test, because it is
>   administered by a machine and targeted at a human, in contrast to the
>   standard Turing test that is typically administered by a human and
>   targeted at a machine.